# Как поймать ошибку Twitter API в PHP и пропустив ее продолжить выполнять скрипт?

Tags: php, twitter-api

Здравствуйте. Я выполняю запрос из PHP к TwitterAPI и если он возвращает мне ошибку типа "You have already favorited this status", то выполнение скрипта на этом завершается. Я пробовал обрабатывать ошибку, чтобы пропустить ее, например так:

```
try {
    $myTweet->like($twit->id);
} catch (OAuthException $e) {

}
```

Но ошибка все равно останавливает скрипт. Этот скрипт не мой, если проблема не изза Twitter API, то просто дайте знать

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: если скрипт останавливает работу, значит вы ловите не тот класс исключения, не?

Comment: Я пробовал и Exception ловить, тоже самое

Comment: ну а внутрь like() заглядывали? может там через die() завершение реаализовано, а вы тут ловить пытаетесь...

Comment: OAuthException - это ошибка авторизации, а у вас ошибка возникает после. Попробуйте ловить \Exception или \Throwable

Comment: Проблема решена, надо было писать `catch (\Exception $e) {`